# Use having on SQL Query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elk

I'm use the next query to get the average of memory used, but only need get data when average is more than x value

```
SELECT AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct) AS averageMemory from "metricbeat*" where  host.name.keyword='data.storage' HAVING AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct)>0.3 and "@timestamp" BETWEEN '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' and '2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z'
```

And show me the next error

> Found 1 problem\nline 1:152: Cannot use HAVING filter on non-aggregate [@timestamp]; use WHERE instead"

And when use WHERE clause, like this

```
SELECT AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct) AS averageMemory from "metricbeat*" where  host.name.keyword='data.storage' and averageMemory>0.3 and "@timestamp" BETWEEN '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' and '2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Show the next error

> Found 1 problem\nline 1:8: Cannot use WHERE filtering on aggregate function [AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct)], use HAVING instead

Im confused. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct)>0.3` is correct, as `HAVING` expresses a constraint on aggregated data, and `WHERE ... averageMemory>0.3` is not correct, as `WHERE` expresses a constraint at record level.

For the same reason, `HAVING @timestamp BETWEEN '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z' and '2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z'` is wrong, since `@timestamp` is not an aggregated value but a record level attribute.

So `WHERE ... and @timestamp BETWEEN '2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z HAVING AVG(system.memory.actual.used.pct)>0.3` should be the correct way.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect